# Query to find how many more items needed to fulfill the preorder

Tags: sql

An online store released their site and has allowed users to pre-order items. They have 'preorders' table that has all the pre-orders made and 'inventory' table has all the items currently in inventory. Preorder went better than expected and they dont have enough items in their inventory to ship to their user. The query should tell the company how many more items are needed in their inventory to fulfill their preorders per item. If there are enough items in inventory, do not include that item in the output.

```
PREORDERS

Name       Type         Description
------------------------------------
Order_id   Integer      Unique_id of the order placed
Name       String       Name of the person who placed the order
State      Integer      The state the person lives in
Item       String       The item purchased

************************************************************************

INVENTORY

Name       Type         Description
------------------------------------
ID          Integer     The Unique ID of the inventory item
Item        String      The name of the item in inventory
Amount      Integer     How many of the items are in inventory
```

(ordered - available), i.e., ordered from the preorders should be subtracted from the available item in the inventory per item, I'm not sure how to put it into query joining two tables as the order_ID from preorder is different from ID from inventory

Comment: Where's the table that contains the number of items pre-ordered?

Comment: ‘Pre-Order’ doesn’t contain anything column that tells us how many items have been purchased. kindly review your question and update it accordingly if you need any help.

Comment: @isha Uh-oh, Looks like you have to count each record, and group it by Item. Then JOIN that into the INVENTORY table.

Comment: I was quite confused with the tables too, but this is all the data that was given. @ZainArshad

Comment: If these tables are accurate, it would indicate that a customer could only pre-order one unit per row.  Also, since there is no `InventoryID` column (in PREORDER), you need the `Item` column to be unique and reliable as a FK.  Not a nice design, but possible.